# Is there really any implementation of a Ada compiler/cross-compiler/interpreter for 6502?

Tags: 6502, compilers, 8-bit-microcomputers, ada

I found [some Ada compilers for CP/M machines](http://www.z80.eu/ADA.html) but no luck for 6502-based C64/Apple II/BBC Micro. I'm not sure if [Abacus Ada on C64](https://www.lyonlabs.org/commodore/onrequest/collections.html) exists or how much a subset it implements for Ada.

There is, though, an Ada inspired [Cowgol](http://cowlark.com/cowgol/), and an [Ada95 compiler](http://computer-programming-forum.com/44-ada/0decf7b0d87ed451.htm) targeting ANSI C as an intermediate language.

Is there really any implementation of a Ada compiler/cross-compiler/interpreter for 6502?
Link:

- [New Frontiers in High-Level 6502
  Programming](https://8bitworkshop.com/blog/compilers/higher-level-6502-programming.md.html)
- [What languages are better fit for generating efficient code for 8-bit CPU's than C?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15004/what-languages-are-better-fit-for-generating-efficient-code-for-8-bit-cpus-than/15011#15011)

Comment: You might find a cross compiler but no native compiler that will compile anything like  a reasonable Ada program. My university created one of the first Ada compilers for DOS but it wasn't complete and it needed 4Mb of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Ada for the 6502 for the Commodore 64 but it is sold out at The Computer Bargain Store: [Abacus Software for Commodore 64 & 128](https://www.oldsoftware.com/Abacus.html). It looks like they once had a used copy but sold it. The Ada Training Course is still available for $69.

If you are interested in other languages that generate efficient 6502 code or are similar to Ada, try these:

The most efficient compiler is likely Action! for the Atari 8-bit computers. It's syntax is derived from ALGOL so is a bit like Ada. It doesn't have FP built in but I believe there is an FP library available.

Another efficient 6502 compiler I've seen is Betterworking's Power C for the C64 which seems to be only 40% slower than assembly, but it is only a partial implementation of C and not very good for more than small projects. Abacus' Super C is a more complete implementation but is only 25% the speed of Power C.

The closest thing to Ada would be Pascal, such as KYAN Pascal but the Commodore 64 version is 30% slower than Power C. It is also available for the Atari 8-bit computers and the Apple II.

PROMAL for the C64 is twice as fast as KYAN Pascal. PROMAL is like C except it's syntax is more like Python, although Python didn't come along until later.

Comment: PROMOL seems like an interesting language, with some features that make it convenient to write constructs which can be processed efficiently.  Something like `*(int*)((unsigned char*)intArray + offset) = 0x1234;`, using offsets that count up by `sizeof (int)`, can on many platforms yield vastly more efficient code than `intArray[index]` with an index that counts by one, but the required syntax is nasty.  By contrast, if memory serves, PROMOL has an operator for just that purpose.

Comment: I used Action! on the Atari when it first came out. It was a pleasure to use - nice IDE, fast compiler, fast code. Almost like having C. I still have the cartridge.

Comment: Action!'s source code was released a few years ago and some bug fixes were made. There was talk on AtariAge about making a stand-alone version that doesn't require the cartridge and of making some enhancements to it.